# how to edit tables dynamically(not manually) in QTableview in qt

Tags: qt4, psql

I am creating a GUI application in Qt in linux.Here in a Tableview i create a table
 which can hold the database values.Now i want to edit my table dynamically with the
 program,so that the table will automatically change as the program needs.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change the tableview.  It uses the Model-View-Controller pattern, so any changes to the model should update in the view automatically.

Comment: If you are having problems where you are changing your model and it isn't updating the view, please clarify.